# Removing handlers from python's logging loggers

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am playing with Python's logging system. I have noticed a strange behavior while removing handlers from a Logger object in a loop. Namely, my for loop removes all but one handler. Additional call to `.removeHandler` removes the last handler smoothly. No error messages are issued during the calls.

This is the test code:

```
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig()
dbg = logging.getLogger('dbg')
dbg.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

testLogger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
fh = logging.FileHandler('mylogfile.log')
dbg.debug('before adding handlers: %d handlers'%len(testLogger.handlers))
testLogger.addHandler(fh)
testLogger.addHandler(sh)

dbg.debug('before removing. %d handlers: %s'%(len(testLogger.handlers), 
                                              str(testLogger.handlers)))
for h in testLogger.handlers:
    dbg.debug('removing handler %s'%str(h))
    testLogger.removeHandler(h)
    dbg.debug('%d more to go'%len(testLogger.handlers))

#HERE I EXPECT THAT NO HANDLER WILL REMAIN    
dbg.debug('after removing: %d handlers: %s'%(len(testLogger.handlers), 
                                              str(testLogger.handlers)))
if len(testLogger.handlers) > 0:
    #Why is this happening?
    testLogger.removeHandler(testLogger.handlers[0])
dbg.debug('after manually removing the last handler: %d handlers'%len(testLogger.handlers))
```

I expect that at the end of the loop no handlers will remain in the `testLogger` object, however
the last call to `.removeHandler` apparently fails, as can be seen from the output below. Nevertheless
additional call to this function removes the handler as expected. Here is the output:

```
DEBUG:dbg:before adding handlers: 0 handlers
DEBUG:dbg:before removing. 2 handlers: [<logging.FileHandler instance at 0x021263F0>, <logging.StreamHandler instance at 0x021262B0>]
DEBUG:dbg:removing handler <logging.FileHandler instance at 0x021263F0>
DEBUG:dbg:1 more to go
DEBUG:dbg:after removing: 1 handlers: [<logging.StreamHandler instance at 0x021262B0>]
DEBUG:dbg:after manually removing the last handler: 0 handlers
```

More interestingly, if I replace the original loop with the following one, the loop
works as expected and no handlers remain in the `testLogger` object at the end of the loop. 
Here is the modified loop:

```
while len(testLogger.handlers) > 0:
    h = testLogger.handlers[0]
    dbg.debug('removing handler %s'%str(h))
    testLogger.removeHandler(h)
    dbg.debug('%d more to go'%len(testLogger.handlers))
```

What explains this behaviour? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: `for h in list(testLogger.handlers)`

Answer (score 162, accepted):

This isn't logger-specific behaviour. *Never* mutate (insert/remove elements) the list you're currently iterating on. If you need, make a copy. In this case `testLogger.handlers.clear()` should do the trick.

Comment: Solution is not so obvious and nice since we need to take into account thread safety which is obviously compromised here (take a look at addHandler implementation - locks are used there to modify handlers list).

Comment: A safer alternative would be to modify the existing list:
`testLogger.handlers.clear()`

Comment: @zenofpython I suppose `testLogger.handlers.clear()` calls the `clear` method of `list` type? Why is it safter than `testLogger.handlers = []`?

Comment: Redefining a list rather than modifying the original list is a problem whenever you use an alias somewhere that points to the original list. Suppose:
`a = b = [1, 2, 3]`
`a = []`
Notice that `b` still points to `[1, 2, 3]`.
In fairness, it is unlikely that you would ever use such an alias *in this case*, but it is good practice to maintain consistency so you don't get any unexpected surprises from cutting corners.

Answer (score 24):

instead of mutating undocumented `.handler`:

### Option 1

```
logging.getLogger().removeHandler(logging.getLogger().handlers[0])
```

this way you remove exactly the preexisting handler object via offical api.  Or to remove all handlers:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
while logger.hasHandlers():
    logger.removeHandler(logger.handlers[0])
```

### Option 2

```
logging.config.dictConfig(config={'level': logging.DEBUG, 'handlers': []})
```

Not only removes but prevents its creation. List root will have `[]` handlers

Comment: Option 1 does not work for non-root loggers: the method `hasHandlers()` also checks the handlers of the ancestor loggers, so if an ancestor logger has an handler then `logger.hasHandlers()` will always evaluate to `True` and therefore `logger.handlers[0]` will end up raising an `IndexError`.

Comment: Going off option 2, you can also just set your instantiated logger object's handlers attribute to an empty array, such as `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and `logger.handlers = []`

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to delete them all (thanks for [the tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7484605/623735) [@CatPlusPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16102/cat-plus-plus)):

```
testLogger.handlers = [
    h for h in testLogger.handlers if not isinstance(h, logging.StreamHandler)]
```

Comment: Sorry,I found this didn't work.for isinstance can't used to judge handler's type

Comment: @fat_cheng Why can't isinstance work for that purpose? I don't seem to have a problem using the suggestion in this answer myself.

Comment: I'm using python3 in Ubuntu 16.04. I use `if (type(h) == logging.StreamHandler)]` instead.

Comment: @fat_cheng you should never do that because `type` doesn't check parent types (inheritance), `isinstance` does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549854/623735

Comment: For personnal purposes i wanted to check that a handker worked without spamming slack channel afterwards.

    `handlers = logger.handlers; logger.error('Removing slack handler');    logger.handlers = [handler for handler in logger.handlers
                       if handler != slack_handler]`

Answer (score 13):

I would say if the intent for removing the logging handlers is to prevent sending logs to additional handlers (this is the case most of the times) then an alternative approach I follow is to set `propagate` to `False` for your current logger.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.propagate = False
```

That way your log messages will only go to the handlers you explicitly add and will not propagate to parent loggers.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

I've just found out that you can also do that within a logging .ini file, with the following block:

```
[logger_stpipe]
handlers=
propagate=1
qualname=stpipe
```

It basically deactivates all handlers for a given logger. But it's somewhat limited because you have to know the Logger's name in advance.