# Scrapy - Log Level. Different behaviour running on AWS Lambda vs Local

Tags: python, logging, scrapy, aws-lambda

I run Scrapy from script https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script to launch a script from AWS Lambda. I compile the project with SAM and everything is correct.

But now, I have the problem with LOG_LEVEL parameter.

```
def handler(event, context):

  settings = {
             'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.85 Safari/537.36',
             'LOG_ENABLED': True,
             'LOG_LEVEL': 'ERROR'
          }

  process = CrawlerProcess(settings=settings)
  process.crawl(Spider)
  process.start()
```

When execute this code in local, all is correct, only receive the LOG_LEVEL: ERROR, but when execute this code in AWS Lambda, I receive the LOG_LEVEL: DEBUG, and I don´t know how to resolve.

Comment: The python environment in Lambda has a preconfigured root logger. I think scrapy might be clashing with that, but I'm not 100% sure. Can you try configuring the scrappy logging manually and use `scrapy.utils.log.configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)` to see if it helps?

Comment: @MilanCermak I tried these configuration but doesn´t work. I put the line before the settings dict, inside Lambda handler. It is correct?

Comment: Yes, that should be ok. What is weird to me is that you get even DEBUG messages. Something is definitely "messing" with the logging setup. Maybe try one more thing - in the top level (outside of the Lambda handler), get the root logger `root = logging.getLogger()` and call the scrappy `configure_logging` with your settings. HTH.

Comment: @MilanCermak I tried with `root = logging.getLogger()` outside of the Lambda handler and `scrapy.utils.log.configure_logging(settings=settings)` (with install_root_handler True and False)  after settings dict and is the same behaviour. It still showing the DEBUG logs. :( Any idea?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, somehow, my comment above missed the main part I wanted to convey - remove all the handlers from the root logger first, before calling the configure function.

Comment: @MilanCermak, can you provide more information? I don't understand your last comment. Thanks for all.

Comment: Try something along these lines https://gist.github.com/milancermak/945b54107d6c238ac079ea2fcd39be29

Comment: Milan, feel free to provide an answer (even copy mine), I’ll delete mine once you do.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the input from the OP in [Scrapy issue #3587](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3587#event-2091957209), it turns out AWS Lambda installs its own handlers on the root logger, so you need to [remove those handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7484605/939364) before you use Scrapy:

```py
from logging import getLogger

getLogger().handlers = []

def handler(event, context):  # AWS Lambda entry point
    pass  # Your code to call Scrapy.
```

Comment: Yes, the OP of Scrapy issue is mine, based in @Milan Cermak help. I am waiting that he posted the answer. But your response is correct too. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Gallaecio, I had another problem with AWS Lambda container and Scrapy. When I execute the code in local, doesn't fail but when execute the code in AWS Lambda containers two times in a short period of time, it produce this error:

I put in the gist: https://gist.github.com/milancermak/945b54107d6c238ac079ea2fcd39be29

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please, open a separate question so that it can be found easily, both by people who know the answer and by people how may have the same question.

Comment: You are right, this is the new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350888/runtime-error-on-aws-lambda-with-scrapy-reuse-container-issue , thanks for all @Gallaecio

Comment: Hey folks. No worries @nicoparsa, feel free to upvote and accept this answer. Glad we found a solution.

Comment: @MilanCermak Thank you so much for all!