# logging in file using Python

Tags: python, logging, info

I did this to save info to my file, but I also got output in my console. What can I do not to see info in my console, but to see it in my file?

```
logger = logging.getLogger('resource_manager')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
info_log = logging.FileHandler('/home/nvidia/Videos/Info.log')
info_log.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s'))
info_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(info_log)

logger.info(f'{(time.time()-delay)}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable propagation of events from this logger to its parent (the root logger), which will prevent them from being handled by the root logger's `StreamHandler` (which is what writes to standard error).

```
logger = logging.getLogger('resource_manager')
logger.propagate = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have added a handler to write to a file.  What you need to do is [remove the default handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484454/removing-handlers-from-pythons-logging-loggers) that writes to STDERR.

Answer (score 0):

> I did this to save info to my file, but I also got output in my console.

That may mean that some other logging configuration is already active (for example, are you sure that `logging.basicConfig()` has not been called in the same Python program?); in particular, that the *root logger* has a `StreamHandler` attached to it.

Loggers are organized in a hierarchy, based on their names; for example, `foo` is the parent of `foo.bar` and `foo.baz`, and `foo.baz` is the parent of `foo.baz.spam`. At the apex of that hierarchy is the *root logger* (i.e., the one *whose name is empty*). By default loggers propagate emitted records (unless the level of a record is too low for the given logger) to their parents (so that finally those records reach the *root* logger).

An easy way to prevent your logger from propagating emitted records to the parent is to set the logger's `propagate` attribute to `False` (by default it is `True`).

So try this:

```
logger.propagate = False
```

Recommended further reading:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger